# Segmentation fault (core dumped) - Error In C

Tags: c, gtk

Below is my file, can anyone tell me why this is throwing this error? I built it originally on a raspberry pi and it ran fine moved it to my ubuntu laptop and now it doesnt work havent modified a thing.

I looked up the error and it said something about a memory error, trying to write to a string thats read only in memory but i dont see anything that is writing to read only memory

```
    #include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>



const gchar *username;
const gchar *password;
const gchar *serverIP;
GtkWidget *wrongTemp;
GtkEntry *userTemp;
GtkEntry *passTemp;
GtkComboBoxText *serverField;
int nlines = 0;





void end_program (GtkWidget *wid, gpointer ptr)
{
 gtk_main_quit ();
}

void hide_error(GtkWidget *wid, gpointer ptr)
{

    gtk_widget_hide(wrongTemp);

}

void readConfig()
{
    //FILE *config = fopen("/home/pi/thinpi/config/servers", "r");
    //char buf[1000];
    //fgets(buf, 1000, config);
    //printf("%s", buf);
     
    FILE* file = fopen("/home/pi/thinpi/config/servers", "r"); 
    char line[256];
    
    

    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file)) {
        nlines++;
        strtok(line, "\n");
        gtk_combo_box_text_append (serverField, NULL,line);
    }
    

    fclose(file);

}


void rdp(const gchar *u, const gchar *p)
{   
    
    char *svr = malloc(50);
    svr = strtok(gtk_combo_box_text_get_active_text(serverField), ":");
    printf("%s\n", svr);
    
    char *cmd = malloc(100);
    sprintf(cmd, "xfreerdp /cert-tofu /size:1920x1080 /f /gdi:hw /smart-sizing:1920x1080 /u:'%s' /p:'%s' /v:%s", u, p, svr);
    int rv = system(cmd);
    if(rv == 0 || rv == 2816) {
        GtkEntry *userReal = userTemp;
        GtkEntry *passReal = passTemp;
        gtk_entry_set_text(userReal, "");
        gtk_entry_set_text(passReal, "");
    } else if(rv != 0) {
        printf("Wrong Username or password\n");
        GtkWidget *wrongReal = wrongTemp;
        gtk_widget_show(wrongTemp);
    }
}

void unameset(GtkWidget *wid, GtkEntry *userp)
{
    system("echo [THINPI] - Setting Username");
    username = gtk_entry_get_text (userp);
    
}

void pwordset(GtkWidget *wid, GtkEntry *pwordp)
{
    system("echo [THINPI] - Setting password");
    password = gtk_entry_get_text (pwordp);
    printf("set username to: %s\n", username);
    printf("set password to: %s\n", password);
    printf("set server to: %s\n", serverIP);
    rdp(username, password);
    
}



void main (int argc, char *argv[])
{


gtk_init (&argc, &argv);

GtkBuilder *builder = gtk_builder_new(); 
gtk_builder_add_from_file(builder, "/home/pi/thinpi/glade/gui.glade", NULL); 

GtkWindow *window1 = (GtkWindow *) gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "thinpiMain"); 
GtkWidget *btn = (GtkWidget *) gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "connect"); 
GtkEntry *user = (GtkEntry *) gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "uname");
GtkEntry *pass = (GtkEntry *) gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "pword");
GtkComboBoxText *serverSelect = (GtkComboBoxText *) gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "serverSelect");
GtkWidget *wrong = (GtkWidget *) gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "wrongLabel");



wrongTemp = wrong;
userTemp = user;
passTemp = pass;
serverField = serverSelect;
readConfig();


 g_signal_connect (btn, "clicked", G_CALLBACK (unameset), user);
 g_signal_connect (btn, "clicked", G_CALLBACK (pwordset), pass);
 g_signal_connect (window1, "delete_event", G_CALLBACK (end_program),
 NULL);
 g_signal_connect (user, "changed", G_CALLBACK (hide_error),
 NULL);
  g_signal_connect (pass, "changed", G_CALLBACK (hide_error),
 NULL);


gtk_window_fullscreen(window1);
gtk_window_present(window1);
gtk_main();


}
```

Comment: Use a debugger, find out the exact location of the error, then try to create a [mcve].

Comment: Or compile and link with the option `-fsanitize=address`, this is very helpful

Comment: @SouravGhosh what debugger should i use??

Comment: Just add `-fsanitize=address` to your compiler and linker command line, rebuild the program entirely (with `-g` too), run it, and it will stop with a stack trace explaining what happened and where exactly it happened in your code.

Comment: @prog-fh ==190196==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: SEGV on unknown address 0x000000000000 (pc 0x7f83e85097d7 bp 0x000000000100 sp 0x7fff6f2a7b30 T0)

Comment: @prog-fh ==190291==The signal is caused by a READ memory access.
==190291==Hint: address points to the zero page.
    #0 0x7f8f84a227d6 in _IO_fgets (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x857d6)
    #1 0x7f8f853f3e1f  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.5+0x53e1f)
    #2 0x5654e416e667 in readConfig src/boot.c:45
    #3 0x5654e416eb01 in main src/boot.c:122
    #4 0x7f8f849c40b2 in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x270b2)
    #5 0x5654e416e44d in _start (/home/kyle/Desktop/thinpi-dev/v1/post/system/thinpi-manager+0x244d)

Comment: Not sure what happens when giving strtok  a function returned pointer as first parameter. BTW , did you check that the config file has no line longer than 255 char (ReadConfig)

Comment: @KyleMendell the stack-trace you show says that in `readConfig()`, at line 45 of `src/boot.c` you gave a NULL pointer to `fgets()`. Probably this is the result of the previous `fopen()` that failed, but you didn't check.

Answer (score 0):

In `unameset` function you wrote this line: `username = gtk_entry_get_text (userp);`. Perhaps this is the reason why it does not work on Ubuntu...I don't know why the raspberry pi compiler didn't flag it.